# Difference between Magistrate court, Sessions Courts, & High Courts

Tags: court, case-law

In India, I've noticed that there are many types of Courts.

For example, within the same city, there are a few Magistrate courts, sessions courts, and a single High Court.

I understand we need more courts so that more cases can be dispensed easily.

But why are they different types of courts? Like, what is the difference between Magistrate courts, sessions courts, and High courts?

Does each court handle only a particular set of cases? Does the High court not entertain certain cases that can only be processed in a Magistrate or a session court? How to understand the difference?